# Does any $f \in C^2$ have locally Lipschitz first derivative with constant as small as one wishes?

Tags: real-analysis

I write a statement that seems intuitively true to me:

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function belonging to $C^2$. Given $\alpha > 0$ and any $y \in \mathbb{R}$ then there always exists a neighborhood $B_{\delta_y}$ around $y$ such that $f'$ is Lipschitz in $B_{\delta_y}$ with constant $L < 1/ \alpha$ .

I attempt a proof:

Taylor expanding $f$ we obtain that
$$f(y) = f(a) + f'(a) (y-a) + f''(c) (y-a)^2 $$
where $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and $c \in ]y,a[$. Then
$$f'(y) = f'(a) + 2f''(c) (y-a)$$
so for any $y_1,y_2 \in \mathbb{R}$
\begin{align*}&|f'(y_1)- f'(y_2)| = |2 f''(c) (y_1-a) -  2 f''(c_1) (y_2-a) | \end{align*}

but I cant seem to conclude. Is the statement true and how would one prove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x^2$ has derivative $2x$, and $\lvert 2x-2y\rvert\le L\lvert x-y\rvert$ holds for no $L<2$ and $x\ne y$.